# Array indexing not updating after deleting one element

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, indexing

After deleting one element from tableStoryArray[], the next element index is not changing or updating due to that when I try to delete the next element it's getting crash with "index out of range".

```
   @IBAction func Btn4Action(_ sender: Any) { // Delete row

        self.tableStoryArray.remove(at: index!.row)
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [index!], with: .middle)
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
        self.tableView.reloadData()


  }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? WriteStoryTableViewCell

        cell?.charNameinStory.text =  self.tableStoryArray[indexPath.row]["charName"] as? String
        cell?.charNameinStory.textColor =  self.tableStoryArray[indexPath.row]["charNameColor"] as? UIColor
        cell?.cellView.backgroundColor =  self.tableStoryArray[indexPath.row]["backgroundcolor"] as? UIColor
        cell?.charImageinStory.image = self.tableStoryArray[indexPath.row]["image"] as? UIImage
        cell?.charRelationinStory.text = self.tableStoryArray[indexPath.row]["charRelation"] as? String
        cell?.textView.text = self.tableStoryArray[indexPath.row]["story"] as? String

        if self.tableStoryArray[indexPath.row]["charName"] as? String != "" {
            cell?.charetailViewHeightConstraint.constant = 38
            cell?.chardetailViewinStory.isHidden = false

        }else{
            cell?.charetailViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0
            cell?.chardetailViewinStory.isHidden = true

        }

        return cell
```

}

Fatal error: Index out of range

Comment: From where you got an index? The error you are getting now is because that doesn't exist on array or tableview's row. You need to find the index first. well you can find it from sender Object(Your Button Object). After finding the index you can check that index exist in array or not.

Comment: if self.tableStoryArray.indices.contains(index!.row) {
    //.. Your logic of deleting stuff.
}
And also do not reload the tableview as you already removed the object form array source and from tableview's row too.

Comment: I am using the tag of textView inside the cell as index = IndexPath(row: textView.tag, section: 0)

Comment: You don't need to use the textView.tag inside of Cell, I mean probably you assigned the first tag value of textView by indexPath.row. In this case you can directly use the value of indexPath.row. Can you please show me the code you did inside of cellForRow?

Comment: But in the code you didn't assign the any value to textView.tag. 
Simply you can follow my suggestion form first and second comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case to update the tags of all cells do not delete the row with `deleteRows` but reload the entire table view

```
@IBAction func Btn4Action(_ sender: Any) { // Delete row
    self.tableStoryArray.remove(at: index!.row)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

And you must assign the tag in `cellForRow`.

By the way force unwrap the cell. A crash at this point reveals a design mistake which can be fixed immediately. And don't get the same object again and again, this is unnecessarily expensive (a custom struct would be even more efficient)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! WriteStoryTableViewCell
   cell.textView.tag = indexPath.row // crucial !!
   let story = self.tableStoryArray[indexPath.row]
   cell.charNameinStory.text =  story["charName"] as? String
   cell.charNameinStory.textColor = story["charNameColor"] as? UIColor     
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

First, do the set tag of **UIButton inside cellForRowIndexPath method**

```
Btn4Action.tag = indexPath.row
```

**Second delete row with a specific button tag.**

```
@IBAction func Btn4Action(_ sender: UIButton) { // Delete row

                        if self.tableStoryArray.indices.contains(sender.tag) {

                            self.tableStoryArray.remove(at: sender.tag)
                            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [sender.tag], with: .middle)
                            self.tableView.endUpdates()
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: I am using the tag of textView inside the cell as

index = IndexPath(row: textView.tag, section: 0)